# Placing specific reference after all others

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a paper in which one specific reference must be placed after all others in the bibliography section.

E.g. all anonymous citations (author="Anonymous") must be placed in the end of the bibliography.

Any idea how to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\noopsort` device: prefix all "Anonymous" authors with `{\noopsort{ZZZZ}}`. The `\noopsort` macro should be defined as taking one input and returning nothing; see the code below for an implementation.

[image]

All "Anonymous" entries will be placed at the end or, more precisely, after "ZZZZ". (You don't have any authors whose names starts with "ZZZZa", do you?) If there are several entries by "Anonymous", they will be sorted first by `year` and second alphabetically by `title`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@preamble { " \providecommand\noopsort[1]{} " }
@misc{x1,
  author = "{\noopsort{ZZZZ}}Anonymous",
  title  = "Random thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
@misc{x2,
  author = "Author, Annie E. ",
  title  = "Deep thoughts",
  year   = 3002,
}
@misc{x3,
  author = "{\noopsort{ZZZZ}}Anonymous",
  title  = "Further thoughts",
  year   = 3003,
}
@misc{x4,
  author = "{\noopsort{ZZZZ}}Anonymous",
  title  = "Final thoughts",
  year   = 3003,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\cite{x1}, \cite{x2}, \cite{x4}, \cite{x3}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. First, many thanks. However, it does not work for me. If I do not put \noopsort{ZZZZ} in the author line, then the reference is being printed in the top (as expected). However, if I put it, then the reference is not being moved to the end, but in the middle(!) between an author with Last Name 'N' and another one with 'O'. Strange...

Comment: You're missing braces: `author="{\noopsort{ZZZZ}}Anonymous"`. I also don't recommend quotes as field delimiters.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for the extra-braces suggestion; I've updated the MWE accordingly.